# Using a variable for defining the training column in the predict function in R

Tags: r, r-caret

Let us say that we have the following code (the training/testing partition for this problem is irrelevant).

```
library(caret)
data(iris)
train( Species ~ .,data=iris, method="rf" )
```

Now this runs fine. What I want to be able to do is to provide the column I am trying to predict using a variable (because I am going to get it from a GUI). Let us use the example code below:

```
library(caret)
data(iris)
colName <- 'Species'
train( colName ~ .,data=iris, method="rf" )
```

This does not work because `colName` is not one of the columns in the dataset. So is there a way of doing this? I have searched high and low and came up with nothing. Someone please help me :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple enough case so using `paste` in the following way should be fine:

```
library(caret)
data(iris)
colName <- 'Species'

#create the formula using as.formula and paste
formula <- as.formula(paste(colName, ' ~ .' ))

#run model
train(formula, data=iris, method="rf" )
```

Output:

```
> train( formula,data=iris, method="rf" )
Random Forest 

150 samples
  4 predictor
  3 classes: 'setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica' 

No pre-processing
Resampling: Bootstrapped (25 reps) 

Summary of sample sizes: 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, ... 

Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  mtry  Accuracy   Kappa      Accuracy SD  Kappa SD  
  2     0.9481249  0.9216819  0.02790700   0.04200793
  3     0.9473557  0.9205465  0.02893104   0.04347956
  4     0.9466284  0.9194525  0.02920803   0.04388548

Accuracy was used to select the optimal model using  the largest value.
The final value used for the model was mtry = 2.
```

Comment: Thanks! I should have seen the function definition. It turns out that there is an `x`, `y` value in the `train` function. So it is also possible to do  `train( iris[,colnames(iris) != colName], iris[,colName], method="rf" )`. Stupid me!

Comment: Np glad I could be of help :). Yeah `caret::train` is indeed quite flexible ! (and don't be too harsh on yourself, we ve all been there :P )

Comment: Keep in ming that you might get (slightly) different models for trees (and a few others) when going between the formula and non-formula interface due to how they treat categorical predictors.